# Add ordered element recursively

Tags: c, recursion

Why do i get segmentation fault on this code?

```
void inserord(Lint *li, int x, Lint *k){

    if(((*li)->value) > x){
        Lint New;
        New = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
        New->value= x;
        New->next = (*li);
        (*k)->next = New;
        return;

    }else if(*li == NULL){
        return;
    }
    *k = *li;
    inserord( &((*li)->next), x, &(*k));
}
```

The problem seems to be when i make *k = *li, they are pointers of the same type, Lint.

This is the data structure:

```
typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist {
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;
```

The idea on the *k, is to pass the previous node to the next recursive call, so i can link this old structure to the new one, and the new to the next.

EDIT:

this is the full code:

```
typedef struct slist *Lint;

typedef struct slist {
    int value;
    Lint next;
} Nodo;

void inserord(Lint *li, int x, Lint *k){
    if(((*li)->value) > x){
        Lint New;
        New = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
        New->value= x;
        New->next = (*li);
        (*k)->next = New;
        return;

    }else if(*li == NULL){
        return;
    }
    *k = *li;
    inserord( &((*li)->next), x, &(*k));
}

void insertend(Lint *l, int x){
    Lint new, aux;

    new = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
    new->value = x;
    new->next = NULL;

    if(*l==NULL){
        *l=new;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(aux=*l; aux!=NULL ; aux = aux->next){
            if(aux->next == NULL){
                aux->next = new;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Lint listinha;

    printf("\n");

    insertend(&listinha, 1);
    insertend(&listinha, 2);
    insertend(&listinha, 3);
    insertend(&listinha, 4);
    insertend(&listinha, 5);
    insertend(&listinha, 7);

    listVal(&listinha);

    Lint k = NULL;

    inserord(&listinha, 4, &k);

    listVal(&listinha);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're wanting to rebuild the list as the stack unwinds you're going to have to return a value (node).

Comment: Lint k=NULL;
inserord(&list, 4, &k);    ---> list is not NULL, only k

Comment: So what's `&list`? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is a pointer to a struct , k and list are pointers to the struct

Comment: Please make an example that shows the `Lint` being passed into that function and what it contains so someone can run it if need be and reproduce the problem. Also, you may want to reconsider your approach if  "...so i can link this old structure to the new one, and the new to the next." is the primary goal. The benefit of recursion is it will return back to the *i-th* call and that's how you link the old with the new.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when the program segfaults? What line is the problem, is it a null pointer dereference or another type of access violation?

Comment: @Christoffer the problem is that i can't see any errors, only "segmentation fault"

Comment: @skills That's interesting -- what debugger are you using? Do you have debug symbols in place?

Comment: i am using gcc, with "gcc -O2 -Wall" i should see warnings if they're there.

Comment: @skills Sorry for the late reply, you did not mention me specifically :-) GCC is a compiler, not a debugger. If you run the original program through GDB instead, it should tell you in pretty much plain text what the problem is, and it will allow you to inspect the program state at crash time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the function simpler the following way

```
Lint inserord( Lint li, int x )
{
    if ( ( li == NULL ) || !( li->value < x ) )
    {
        Lint new_li = malloc( sizeof( Nodo ) );
        new_li->value = x;
        new_li->next = li;

        return new_li;
    }

    li->next = inserord( li->next, x );

    return li;
}
```

and call it like

```
Lint listinha = NULL;

listinha = inserord( listinha, 1 );
```

If to use your approach then the function can be written the following way (I used my own variable names because it is easy to me)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Nodo
{
    int value;
    struct Nodo *next;
};

void inserord( struct Nodo **current, int x, struct Nodo **prev )
{
    if ( ( *current == NULL ) || !( ( *current )->value < x ) )
    {
        struct Nodo *nodo = malloc( sizeof( struct Nodo ) );

        nodo->value = x;
        nodo->next = *current;

        if ( *prev == *current ) *current = nodo;
        else ( *prev )->next = nodo;

        return;
    }

    prev = current;
    current = &( *current )->next;

    inserord( current, x, prev );
}

void display( struct Nodo *current )
{
    for ( ; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Nodo *head = NULL;

    for ( int i = 10; i != 0;  ) inserord( &head, --i, &head );

    display( head );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or if you want to call it with the third parameter like a pointer to NULL then the function can look like

```
void inserord( struct Nodo **current, int x, struct Nodo **prev )
{
    if ( ( *current == NULL ) || !( ( *current )->value < x ) )
    {
        struct Nodo *nodo = malloc( sizeof( struct Nodo ) );

        nodo->value = x;
        nodo->next = *current;

        if ( *prev == NULL ) *current = nodo;
            //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        else ( *prev )->next = nodo;

        return;
    }

    prev = current;
    current = &( *current )->next;

    inserord( current, x, prev );
}
```

and be called like

```
struct Nodo *head = NULL;
struct Nodo *prev = NULL;


for ( int i = 10; i != 0;  ) inserord( &head, --i, &prev );
```

Comment: Greatly done! Makes much sense. Although would like to know what is going on at my code, as i am getting frustrated with it. But i guess sometimes it's better to get around a problem and let go the older solution.

Comment: Note: consider `Lint new_li = malloc(sizeof *new_li);`.  No question right size was requested, better information hiding, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The error may be the case *li is NULL. Indeed, you test it, but you do so only after checking `((*li)->value) > x)` which will get expanded to `(NULL->value > x)` which will segfault.

What you need to do is simply swap the if / else if, like this :

```
void inserord(Lint *li, int x, Lint *k){

/* This check must be done before attempting any other attempt to dereference (*li) */
if(*li == NULL){
    return;
}
else if(((*li)->value) > x){
    Lint New;
    New = (Lint) calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
    New->value= x;
    New->next = (*li);
    (*k)->next = New;
    return;

}
*k = *li;
inserord( &((*li)->next), x, &(*k));

}
```

Segfault may also occur when trying to access `(*k)->next`, which will segfault in the case *k is NULL.

Please provide a main or some snippet where you actually call inserord with the declaration of both `li` and `k`.

Comment: Unfortunately, they seem to know `*li` *isn't `null`?

Comment: it is not NULL indeed, the code still gets me to a segmentation fault.

Comment: I edited the answer, adding the part about (*k)->next. Thanks for providing your main. I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: @clement_frndz How are you going to insert a new value in an empty list if the function exits at once by the condition if(*li == NULL){
    return;?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Indeed my solution doesn't provide this functionality but neither did op's. I upvoted your solution which actually seems to fit op's needs. Beware of the negation though, li->value > x <=> !( li->value < **=** x ).
lldb told me your program received segfault on this line : if(aux->next == NULL) in your insertEnd function

Comment: Vlad, you're totally right, but the thing is, i do know that the original list will never be empty.